# How to take screenshot of UIScrollView visible area?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

How do I take a 1:1 screenshot of UIScrollView visible area? The content may be larger or smaller than UIScrollView bounds as well as half-hidden (I've implemented custom scrolling for smaller content, so it's not in the top-left corner).
I've achieved desired result on simulator, but not on device itself:

```
-(UIImage *)imageFromCombinedContext:(UIView *)background {
      UIImage *image;
      CGRect vis = background.bounds;
      CGSize size = vis.size;
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
      [background.layer affineTransform];
      [background.layer renderInontext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
      image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
      CGImageRef imref = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], vis);
      image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imref];
      CGImageRelease(imref);
      return image;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found a solution myself - I took screenshot of the whole view and then crop it to the size and position of `UIScrollView` frame.

```
-(UIImage *)imageFromCombinedContext:(UIView *)background 
{
      UIImage *image;
      CGSize size = self.view.frame.size;
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
      [background.layer affineTransform];
      [self.view.layer.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
      image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
      CGImageRef imgRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage],background.frame);
      image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imref];
      CGImageRelease(imref);
      return image;
}
```

Comment: I still have to wait 20 hours )

Comment: Isn't this horribly inefficient for large scroll views? What's wrong with the answer from @AbduliamRehmanius answer?

Comment: @AbuliamRegmanius Answer is the better one! Its more efficient.

Answer (score 33):

Another approach would be to use the `contentOffset` to adjust the layer's visible area and capture **only** the currently visible area of `UIScrollView`.

```
UIScrollView *contentScrollView;....//scrollview instance

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(contentScrollView.bounds.size, 
                                       YES, 
                                       [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

//this is the key
CGPoint offset=contentScrollView.contentOffset;
CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), -offset.x, -offset.y); 

[contentScrollView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *visibleScrollViewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Cheers :)

Comment: this is a lot simpler and memory optimized as there is no need to crop a bigger image.

Comment: This answer is the only one that worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Anyone have luck with this on Swift? I have a "zoomable" scrollview, calling this extension function and getting an empty image:

func screenshot() -> UIImage
{
     let offset = self.contentOffset
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
     CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), -offset.x, -offset.y)
     self.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
     let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
     return image
}

Comment: Worked for me in zoomable scrollview in swift. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Swift version of Abduliam Rehmanius answer.

```
func screenshot() -> UIImage {

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.scrollCrop.bounds.size, true, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale);
        //this is the key
        let offset:CGPoint = self.scrollCrop.contentOffset;
        CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), -offset.x, -offset.y);
        self.scrollCrop.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!);
        let visibleScrollViewImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return visibleScrollViewImage;
    }
```

**Swift 4 version:**

```
func screenshot() -> UIImage {
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.scrollCrop.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
        let offset = self.scrollCrop.contentOffset
        let thisContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        thisContext?.translateBy(x: -offset.x, y: -offset.y)
        self.scrollCrop.layer.render(in: thisContext!)
        let visibleScrollViewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
return visibleScrollViewImage
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4 version of Abduliam Rehmanius answer as `UIScrollView extension` with translation, no slow cropping

```
extension UIScrollView {

    var snapshotVisibleArea: UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size)
        UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()?.translateBy(x: -contentOffset.x, y: -contentOffset.y)
        layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Jeffery Sun has the right answer. Just put your scroll view inside another view. Get container view to render in context. done.

In the code below, cropView contains the scroll view to be captured. The solution is really just that simple.

As I understand the question and why I found this page, the whole content of the scroll view isn't wanted - just the visible portion.

```
func captureCrop() -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.cropView.frame.size, true, 0.0)
    self.cropView.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Abduliam Rehmanius's answer has poor performance, since if the `UIScrollView` contains a large content area, we will draw that entire content area (even outside the visible bounds).
@Concuror's answer has the issue that it will also draw anything that is on top of the `UIScrollView`.

My solution was to put the `UIScrollView` inside a `UIView` called `containerView` with the same bounds and then render `containerView`:

```
containerView.renderInContext(context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3.0 :

```
 func captureScreen() -> UIImage? {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.yourScrollViewName.bounds.size, true, UIScreen.main.scale)
    let offset:CGPoint = self.yourScrollViewName.contentOffset;
    UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!.translateBy(x: -offset.x, y: -offset.y);
    self.yourScrollViewName.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```

and use it as :
let Image = captureScreen()

Answer (score 0):

Update swift 3+, 4 on @Concuror code

```
func getImage(fromCombinedContext background: UIView) -> UIImage {
        var image: UIImage?
        let size: CGSize = view.frame.size
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
        background.layer.affineTransform()
        view.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        let imgRef = image?.cgImage?.cropping(to: background.frame)
        image = UIImage(cgImage: imgRef!)
        // CGImageRelease(imgRef!) // Removing on Swift - 'CGImageRelease' is unavailable: Core Foundation objects are automatically memory managed
        return image ?? UIImage()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the answers use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext (pre iOS 10.0) to create an image, this creates an image missing the P3 colour gamut - reference https://stackoverflow.com/a/41288197/2481602

```
extension UIScrollView {
    func asImage() -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
        
            inputView?.layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
            layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
    }
}
```

The above will result in a better quality image being produced.

The second image is clearer, and showing more of the colours - this was done with the UIGraphicsImageRenderer rather than the UIGraphicsBeginImageContext (first Image)

[image: UIGraphicsBeginImageContext method]

[image: UIGraphicsImageRenderer method]