# iOS - Take screen shot of UIScrollView visible area with size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10976816/how-to-take-screenshot-of-uiscrollview-visible-area) and the answer is perfect. But what if I want so set the size myself? How do I change the `scrollView.contentOffset` for this?

For Example I want to call it like this:

```
#define multiplier 3.0f

CGSize size = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.size.width*multiplier, scrollView.frame.size.height*multiplier); 
UIImage *backgroungImage = [self renderScrollViewToImageWith:scrollView size:size];

-(UIImage *)renderScrollViewToImageWith:(UIScrollView *)_scrollView size:(CGSize)size
{
    UIScrollView *contentScrollView = _scrollView;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);

    //what do I do here???
    CGPoint offset = contentScrollView.contentOffset;
    CGContextTranslateCTM(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), -offset.x, -offset.y); <-- what do I do here?

    [contentScrollView drawViewHierarchyInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height) afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *visibleScrollViewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return visibleScrollViewImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CGRect croppingRect = viewToTakeScreenShot.bounds;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(croppingRect.size, NO, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
if (context == NULL) return nil;
CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -croppingRect.origin.x, -croppingRect.origin.y);

[viewToTakeScreenShot layoutIfNeeded];
[viewToTakeScreenShot.layer renderInContext:context];

UIImage *screenshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Try this. It can be help for you.